# Why does git shell alias double command line arguments?

Tags: git, bash, shell, alias

Git seems to double command-line arguments provided to its shell aliases. For example, if you create an alias that takes a single argument, then when you will try to use it, the argument would be concatenated to itself as if it was provided twice.

Why is this happening?

This demonstration was tested with the latest Git 2.10 release:

```
$ git config alias.foo '!echo "$1"'
$ git foo bar
bar bar
$ git config alias.foo '!echo "$1" "$2"'
$ git foo bar qux
bar qux bar qux
```

Comment: Git aliases don't really take parameters. When the aliases is evaluated, it *does*, however, use arguments in expanding the alias, but the resulting command still receives all the given arguments.

Comment: Try `git config alias.foo '!echo'`.

Comment: Compare with `git config alias.foo '!echo'`; `git foo a b`.

Comment: Thanks, @chepner's comment made it clear.

Comment: Still, `git config alias.foo '!sh -c "echo $1" '` works fine, why?

Comment: Because the shell launched by the resulting alias ignores its argument (`$1` having already been expanded when the alias was expanded). `git foo bar` would expand to something like `sh -c "echo bar" bar`. (And a good thing, because `$1` in the argument to `-c` isn't actually the first argument; that is used to set `$0`. That's another story, though.)

Comment: I'm avoiding actually posting an answer, because I don't really understand *why* it would be useful to have parameters used both to expand the alias and subsequently be passed to the expansion. I'm really just pointing out a theory that is consistent with the observed results.